# Extract components and add to string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have many insert statements in this format:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (MY_ID, MY_NAME) VALUES(l_some_variable,'SOME NAME');
```

I need to change it so they take this form:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (MY_ID, MY_NAME) VALUES(l_some_variable, 'SOME NAME') RETURNING MY_ID INTO t_capital('l_some_variable ---- SOME NAME');
```

essentially needing to add to the end: `RETURNING MY_ID INTO t_capital('[variable_name] ---- [name of the string]')`

There are 10's of thousands of statements that make this very tedious if done manually. I am very bad at regex and haven't been able to figure it out in notepad++.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the full/actual returning clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `INSERT INTO MY_TABLE \(MY_ID, MY_NAME\) VALUES\((\w+),'([^']+)'\)\K(?=;)`
- Replace with: `RETURNING MY_ID INTO t_capital\('$1 ---- $2'\)`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE \(MY_ID, MY_NAME\) VALUES\(
(\w+)           # group 1, 1 or more word character
,'              # literally
([^']+)         # group 2, 1 or more any character that is not single quote
'\)             # literally
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
(?=;)           # positive lookahead, make sure we have a semicolon after
```

**Replacement:**

```
RETURNING MY_ID INTO t_capital\('$1 ---- $2'\)      # in Notepad++, parenthesis hav2 to be escaped in replacement part
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may try doing the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^INSERT INTO (\w+) \((\w+)(.*VALUES.*);
Replace: INSERT INTO $1 ($2$3 RETURNING $2 INTO t_capital('l_some_variable ---- SOME NAME');
```

### Demo

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. The ending shouldn't return the literal string 'l_some_variable ---- SOME NAME'. This is different for every insert statement. For example, the next insert statement could need to be t_capital('l_some_other_variable ---- SOME OTHER NAME');

Comment: Regex can only replace with either a) what is scanned in the input or b) hard coded values.  Do the values in the returning clause either appear in the insert or else are always fixed?

Comment: Yes, they appear in the insert statement So the dynamic values would be 1) l_some_variable and 2) "Some Name'.  So it could be l_some_varaible_2 and 'Some Name2" for example as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Viable patterns might look similar to](https://regex101.com/r/UAyDs5/1) ...

```
/^INSERT\s+INTO\s+(?<table>.*?)\s+\((?<id>.*?),\s*(?<name>.*?)\)\s+VALUES\((?<value1>.*?),\s*'(?<value2>.*?)'\);$/gm;
```

The regex is PCRE(2) and ECMAScript compatible. A JavaScript replacement example which utilizes the above pattern then could look like that ...

```js
const regXCapture =
  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/UAyDs5/1]
  /^INSERT\s+INTO\s+(?<table>.*?)\s+\((?<id>.*?),\s*(?<name>.*?)\)\s+VALUES\((?<value1>.*?),\s*'(?<value2>.*?)'\);$/gm;

const sampleData =
`INSERT INTO FOO (barId, bazName) VALUES(bizVal, 'buzzVal');
INSERT INTO BAR (bazId, bizName) VALUES(buzzVal, 'boozVal');`

console.log(
  sampleData.replace(
    regXCapture,
    "INSERT INTO $1 ($2, $3) VALUES($4, '$5') RETURNING $2 INTO t_capital('$4 ---- $5');"
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```